# How to pass a variable from javascript to symfony2 controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I have a modal with some datas in a table and a radio button beside each row. Everytime I click that radio button, the corresponding datas will be stored in an array after clicking a button. Now, I have a problem in passing a variable from the javascript to my controller which is the 6th index of my array.

Based on what I have researched, most of the solutions were using ajax. I have already tried all the possible codes that I can in my controller but seems like it's not receiving anything. The data I sent in my ajax call did not reach the controller.
Here is my twig file:

```
<button type="button" id="selectrow" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-spacing">Select</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectrow').click(function () {
          var data = selected[6];

                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "project/edit/",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { "data": data },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("OK");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("fail");
                    }
        });
});
```

The selected variable is where I stored the selected data somewhere in the file respectively. And below is my controller, I tried to display the following but the outputs are all null.

```
public function editAction(Request $request) {
       if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
          dump($request->getContent());
       }    

       dump($request->request->get('data'));
       dump($request->query->get('data'));
}
```

I am just really confused because after clicking the button it alerts 'OK' however, the data is not being sent to the controller. Can someone help me with this? It will really be appreciated, thank you.

This is the output that I get:

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you show us the whole form as well as the output you get from PHP?

Comment: It only displays null.

Comment: try to add  `datatype : "application/json"` to your ajax call

Comment: The outputs are still the same: null. Also, I really wonder why the output is displayed after I refreshed the page. Isn't that it will only displayed after the button is being clicked?

Comment: Its an ajax call I don´t know how `dump` and ajax behaves, but I guess It does not work like that. So I would return the data in the controller and output it in some way with `console.log(...)` inside `success: function (data) {`. I guess `selected[6]` is `null`. Can you show us what `selected` is and how you get it?

Comment: selected[6] is not null, I'm pretty sure with it. Because I "alert(selected[6])" it before adding it in the ajax call.

Comment: Can I ask what is the expected output if I will do this inside `success`: `function (data) { console.log(data); }`? @goulashsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you refresh the page which means that you call the controller without any `data` at all. What happens before that is that *jQuery* calls your `editAction` method and waits for a response that never appears because you return nothing in the Controller which is peculiar because you should get an Error saying that a `Controller should return a Response`.

So what you have to ways to make sure the Controller receives the `data` from `jQuery`:

1. `dump` and `die`:

   ```
   public function editAction(Request $request) {
       if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
           dump($request->getContent());
       }    
       dump($request->request->get('data'));
       dump($request->query->get('data'));
       die(); // terminate the current script
   }
   ```
2. Return the `data` in a response and handle it in `jQuery`s `success`:

   In the Controller:

   ```
   return new JsonResponse($request->request->get('data'));
   ```

   In `jQuery`s success:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#selectrow').click(function () {
           var dataSend = selected[6];

                   jQuery.ajax({
                       url: "project/edit/",
                       type: "GET",
                       data: { "data": dataSend },
                       success: function (data) {
                           console.log(data...);
                           if(data == dataSend) console.log("equivalent");
                       },
                       error: function (data) {
                           alert("fail");
                       }
           });
   });
   ```

   I don´t know what type the `data` variable. In case it is just a String or a Number you can just `console.log(data)` which should output the value in the browser console.

Please leave a comment if that works...

Comment: Thank you @goulashsoup, but I forgot to tell that in my controller, I already have something to return- in which I rendered a twig file.  `return->$this->render('AcmeBundle:Project:edit.html.twig, array('someData => $someData ));` So, by this, is it still possible to return the JsonResponse? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'm really new to PHP and Symfony2 so I just barely know a thing.

Comment: @Dianne What do you want to achieve with the Controller? I thought you just want to get the variable into the Controller and do something with it... Ajax is an asynchronous call: It STARTS in javascript and ENDS in javascript so whatever you do in the Controller, what you return in it gets returned in javascript which is in this case the `data` variable in success: `function (data) {...}`...

Comment: Yes, yes, I already get it. I found the error yesterday and it's just in the URL. Thank you, anyways.

Comment: My problem right now is that I can't use the variable that I received in the controller. It says 'internal server error'. Or shall I say I would like to use it as a parameter in find() method so that it will get all the data related to that variable. `$data = $request->query->get('data');` then `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Project')->find($data);`

Comment: @Dianne What is the message of the `internal server error`?